# Dual screen with touch on the 2nd monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

Hello guys i've got the following issue, I have 2 monitors at the moment 1 with touch and one without touch. The one with touch is connected via VGA, and the other one is on HDMI. Now what I want is that I can use the 2nd monitor for touch and the main monitor with the mouse. So far everytime I touch my 2nd monitor it applies to the main monitor and not the touch monitor ( I see my mouse move on the 1st monitor while touching the 2nd). What I want is that when I touch my 2nd monitor it also applies to that one and not the 1st.

Please note that I'm using expand and not duplicate (and using duplicate is not an option for this situation). I've tried going to Tablet-PC settings but that does not solve the problem. As such I'm wondering if it is even possible.

Comment: I'm not sure where you'd find it, but I'd try to look for a way to make your second monitor an absolute instead of relative pointing device.

Answer (score -1):

With traditional touch screen is a matter of the driver. Typically you can configure them as displacement or as absolute position (you want the latter). Then you just need to do the calibration so it knows where you are touching. I only see possible problems if your extended desktop is configured as one long screen instead of as two screens (which is pretty unusual this days).